# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, runtimeexception

```
 07-29 05:43:22.256 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/DICTIONARY: Initialized for the first time
    07-29 05:43:22.392 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4855K, 24% free 15901K/20888K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 9ms
    07-29 05:43:22.516 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 3713K, 21% free 16560K/20888K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 10ms
    07-29 05:43:22.644 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 3894K, 19% free 17259K/21288K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 10ms
    07-29 05:43:22.784 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4181K, 20% free 18020K/22340K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 15ms
    07-29 05:43:22.784 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
    07-29 05:43:22.920 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4293K, 19% free 18936K/23244K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 12ms
    07-29 05:43:23.080 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4668K, 19% free 19943K/24480K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 28ms
    07-29 05:43:23.244 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5098K, 19% free 21035K/25836K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 22ms
    07-29 05:43:23.428 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5568K, 20% free 21846K/27276K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 18ms
    07-29 05:43:23.576 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5620K, 20% free 22842K/28388K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 18ms
    07-29 05:43:23.748 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5909K, 20% free 239        07K/29696K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 20ms
    07-29 05:43:23.944 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6264K, 21% free 24772K/31204K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 17ms
    07-29 05:43:23.944 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
    07-29 05:43:24.140 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6276K, 20% free 25908K/32356K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 18ms
    07-29 05:43:24.140 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
    07-29 05:43:24.344 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6581K, 20% free 27114K/33872K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 22ms
    07-29 05:43:24.344 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
    07-29 05:43:24.588 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6847K, 20% free 28632K/35364K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 25ms
    07-29 05:43:25.100 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 7586K, 21% free 29210K/36924K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 32ms
    07-29 05:43:25.844 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 155 bytes, free space 12 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.172 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 20259K, 53% free 17639K/37472K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 25ms
    07-29 05:43:26.216 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 744 bytes, free space 499 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.272 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1198 bytes, free space 2 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.280 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 40% free 22517K/37472K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 8ms
    07-29 05:43:26.340 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 110 bytes, free space 53 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.400 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 642 bytes, free space 431 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.424 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 47K, 23% free 29148K/37472K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 11ms
    07-29 05:43:26.476 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 36 bytes, free space 35 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.552 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1238 bytes, free space 380 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.652 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 295 bytes, free space 170 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.680 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 172K, 1% free 37165K/37472K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 22ms
    07-29 05:43:26.680 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
    07-29 05:43:26.768 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1833 bytes, free space 1392 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.860 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 737 bytes, free space 171 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:26.940 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 1% free 45285K/45416K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 23ms
    07-29 05:43:26.980 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 905 bytes, free space 85 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.108 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 370 bytes, free space 281 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.240 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1146 bytes, free space 60 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.456 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 1% free 53325K/53608K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 49ms
    07-29 05:43:27.456 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
    07-29 05:43:27.576 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1000 bytes, free space 551 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.720 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 547 bytes, free space 383 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.836 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1028 bytes, free space 326 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:27.904 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 1% free 61512K/61644K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 35ms
    07-29 05:43:27.904 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
    07-29 05:43:28.000 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1        079 bytes, free space 663 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.136 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 628 bytes, free space 539 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.264 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 352 bytes, free space 257 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.308 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 230K, 1% free 69472K/69832K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 24ms
    07-29 05:43:28.308 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
    07-29 05:43:28.404 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 8 bytes, free space 0 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.552 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 612 bytes, free space 246 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.680 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1180 bytes, free space 629 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:28.736 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 77663K/77792K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 41ms
    07-29 05:43:28.736 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
    07-29 05:43:28.884 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 15 bytes, free space 0 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.032 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 261 bytes, free space 41 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.204 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1631 bytes, free space 224 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.244 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 85851K/85980K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 32ms
    07-29 05:43:29.244 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
    07-29 05:43:29.396 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 1081 bytes, free space 77 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.536 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 983 bytes, free space 724 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.620 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 99.625MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:29.620 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 344K, 1% free 93698K/94172K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 34ms
    07-29 05:43:29.620 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms
    07-29 05:43:29.744 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 235 bytes, free space 174 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.900 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/CursorWindow: Window is full: requested allocation 2302 bytes, free space 2044 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
    07-29 05:43:29.956 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:29.956 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 98172K/98304K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 34ms
    07-29 05:43:29.960 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
    07-29 05:43:29.960 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3146-byte allocation
    07-29 05:43:30.016 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 103.987MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:30.016 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 10K, 1% free 98162K/98304K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
    07-29 05:43:30.064 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 103.998MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:30.068 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 98173K/98304K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 47ms
    07-29 05:43:30.068 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
    07-29 05:43:30.068 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1160-byte allocation
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 103.998MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 1% free 98172K/98304K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 1160-byte allocation.
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa6225938 self=0xb7fc08e8
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=3308 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1216368480
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 7006311432 1406884302 2716 ) utm=621 stm=78 core=0
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    07-29 05:43:30.112 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary.DictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords(DictionaryDatabaseHelper.java:90)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary.Dictionary_list.onCreate(Dictionary_list.java:65)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    07-29 05:43:30.116 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-29 05:43:30.148 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 103.998MB to 96.000MB
    07-29 05:43:30.148 3308-3312/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 98173K/98304K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 33ms
    07-29 05:43:30.148 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
    07-29 05:43:30.148 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 184-byte allocation
    07-29 05:43:30.188 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 82975K, 84% free 15197K/94240K, paused 40ms, total 40ms
    07-29 05:43:30.192 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    07-29 05:43:30.192 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6224908)
    07-29 05:43:30.192 3308-3308/com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                 at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
                                                                                 at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                 at com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary.DictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords(DictionaryDatabaseHelper.java:90)
                                                                                 at com.example.sharecorn.wordydictionary.Dictionary_list.onCreate(Dictionary_list.java:65)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am new  in SQLite.I am developing a dictionary app using SQLite database.I am using a dictionary file which consists all words,size is nearly 5MB. 
When I'm running the app in a virtual machine,I am getting the error mentioned above.
Here is my DatabaseHelper class

```
 public class DictionaryDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

final static String ITEM_ID_COLUMN = "id";
final static String WORD_COLUMN = "word";
final static String DEFINATION_COLUMN = "defination";
final static String DICTIONARY_DATABASE = "dictionary";//name of our database


final static String CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+" ( "+
        ITEM_ID_COLUMN+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        WORD_COLUMN+" TEXT , "+
        DEFINATION_COLUMN+" TEXT)";
//command for upgrading database(delete)
final static  String ON_UPGRADE_QUERY = "DROP TABLE"+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;


Context context;

public DictionaryDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DICTIONARY_DATABASE, factory, version);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);//create the databse

}

@Override
//if we upgrade the database
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    database.execSQL(ON_UPGRADE_QUERY);
    onCreate(database);
}

public long insertData(WordDefination wordDefination){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN,wordDefination.word);        values.put(DEFINATION_COLUMN,wordDefination.defination);

    return database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE,null,values);

}

public long updteData(WordDefination wordDefination){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN,wordDefination.word);
    values.put(DEFINATION_COLUMN,wordDefination.defination);

    return database.update(DICTIONARY_DATABASE,values,WORD_COLUMN+"=?",new String[]{wordDefination.word});//jodi wordDefination.word mile jay tobe amra update korte chai


}


public void deleteData(WordDefination wordDefination){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString = "DELETE FROM"+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+"WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+"='"+wordDefination.word+"'";//deleting from the word column (sigle quotation must)

    database.execSQL(queryString);

}

public ArrayList<WordDefination> getAllWords(){
    ArrayList<WordDefination> arrayList = new ArrayList<WordDefination>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectAllQueryString = "SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;//SELECT EVERYTHING FROM DICTIONARY DATABASE
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            WordDefination wordDefination = new WordDefination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINATION_COLUMN)));//object of arraylist with word and defination
            arrayList.add(wordDefination);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());//loop untill next element is present
    }

    return  arrayList;
}

//search word defination by word
public WordDefination getWordDefination(String word) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefination wordDefination = null;//if nothing found

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+ " WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+" = '"+word+ "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {//moving the cursor to first
        wordDefination = new WordDefination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINATION_COLUMN)));//object of arraylist with word and defination

    }
    return wordDefination;

}

//Search word definition by id
public WordDefination getWordDefination(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefination wordDefination = null;//if nothing found

    String selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM" + DICTIONARY_DATABASE + "WHERE" + ITEM_ID_COLUMN + "= '" + id + "'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {//moving the cursor to first
        wordDefination = new WordDefination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINATION_COLUMN)));//object of arraylist with word and defination

    }
    return wordDefination;

}

//to minimize the transaction time we initialize the whole database at one time
public  void initializeDatabaseForFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefination> wordDefinations){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("BEGIN");

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    for(WordDefination wordDefination : wordDefinations){
        contentValues.put(WORD_COLUMN,wordDefination.word);
        contentValues.put(DEFINATION_COLUMN,wordDefination.defination);
        database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE,null,contentValues);
    }


    database.execSQL("COMMIT");
}

}
```

I want to know why I am getting the exception? Is the size of dictionary file causing the exception or anything else? And what is the solution?

Comment: show full stack trace

Comment: show me your logcat.

Comment: i assume you are overloading the program stack with such big files, especially if there are too much lines in it. But to be sure, show your whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I found that you didn't close the `Cursor` in your method `ArrayList<WordDefination> getAllWords()` and `ArrayList<WordDefination> getAllWords()`. So, I wonder how did you call the method and how many times?

Moreover, it's bad design for `SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;` because your database is large.

Answer (score 0):

first cursor have problem, you didn't close.

More about avoid static in your code, if very necessary then you should use.It also gives us problem about out of memory.
You can check here for more details how we can optimize memory in android app.
Here is [link](https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8#.ijbdnz5tu)

Hope this will help you.